# Strange bug? Deadline Exceeded when URLs are "long"

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I have a router that takes a URL, and according to what is passed into the `query` parameter, performs a urlfetch with that query.

Examples of `query` can be:

- `php-mysql`
- `desarrolladores-php-mysql`
- `recepcionista-en-barcelona`
- `recepcionista-hotel-turno-noche/2` (query: recepcionista-hotel-turno-noche; page: 2)

I've been experiencing some extremely strange behavior. When the `query`is long (around 27 characters or more), whenever I try going to the second page, it takes for ever to process the request on the dev_appserver, and in Production hits a DeadlineExceededError. This is strange because I can always fetch the first page, but never the ones after that when the `query`is long.

If you look at my router code, I've added a "print" to see if the code is reaching this part, which is even before the router is set. And whenever it takes so long to load, the log doesn't even print the line, as if it gets stuck somewhere before this portion of the code, which is pretty much as early on in the code as it can get...

Can this be something with the SDK?

## Router

```
from webapp2 import WSGIApplication, Route
from search.get_ads import URI_QUERY_REGEX # a simple variable who's values is: r"([a-z0-9-#,&áéíúóñäëïöüàèìòùç']+)"
import os

print "Router" # This line is for debugging

app = WSGIApplication([
    Route(r'/', handler='app.home.Home'),
    Route(r"/<query:%s+>" % URI_QUERY_REGEX, handler='app.serp.Search'),
    Route(r"/<query:%s+>/<page:[\d]>" % URI_QUERY_REGEX, handler='app.serp.Search'),
    ],
    debug=True if config['env'] == 'dev' else False, config=config
)
```

Notice there are two URLs that can point to the search handler:

- `r"/<query:%s+>"` --> First page of results
- `r"/<query:%s+>/<page:[\d]>"` --> Second page, and further

## app.serp.Search

```
def get(self, query, page=0):
    q = query.split('-')
    # ...
    # Does stuff to clean query and sends a urlfetch to fetch ads according to query. I dont think the issue lies here...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix this. Apparently it was the string substitution. I tried to simply concatenate the strings instead, and works fine now.

```
uri_query_1st_page = r"/<query:" + URI_QUERY_REGEX + ">"
uri_query_more_pages = uri_query_1st_page + r"/<page:[\d]>"

## App Routes ##
app = WSGIApplication([
    Route(r'/', handler='app.home.Home'),
    Route(uri_query_1st_page, handler='app.serp.Search'),
    Route(uri_query_more_pages, handler='app.serp.Search'),
    ],
    debug=True if config['env'] == 'dev' else False, config=config
)
```

Comment: You should accept your own answer to indicate this question is closed.

Comment: I can't yet, I have to wait 3 more hours... :/

Answer (score 0):

I think that all of your search requests are matching the `/<query:%s+>` regex, and so not getting to the `/<query:%s+>/<page:[\d]>` one.

You just need to switch the last two Route(..) entries around:

```
app = WSGIApplication([
    Route(r'/', handler='app.home.Home'),
    Route(r"/<query:%s+>/<page:[\d]>" % URI_QUERY_REGEX, handler='app.serp.Search'),
    Route(r"/<query:%s+>" % URI_QUERY_REGEX, handler='app.serp.Search'),
    ],
    debug=True if config['env'] == 'dev' else False, config=config
)
```